# WPF Label IsMouseOver style doesn't work after click

Tags: wpf, triggers, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I have a label in my UI and have a style for it.

```
<Style x:Key="ColorChangingLabel" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ff676767"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffEAECEE"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ff0067B0"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Besides `MouseOver` trigger i also want to set the same property values when the label is clicked(as click event is not available for label i use MouseDown event).
Here is `MouseDown` event code

```
private void myLabel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
     myLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x00, 0x67, 0xB0));
     myLabel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xea, 0xec, 0xee));
}
```

So my problem is if i mouse down on my label, after it my MouseOver style is never applied to my label. I know about style overriding, but don't know how to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MouseDown` handler is setting a **local value** for the `Foreground` and `Background`, and local values take precedence over all other value sources, including those set by triggers and setters.  See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Use `SetCurrentValue` to change the current property value without switching to a local value:

```
myLabel.SetCurrentValue(
    Control.ForegroundProperty,
    SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0x00, 0x67, 0xB0)));
```

Alternatively, apply a custom style to `myLabel` that uses triggers to change the `Foreground` and `Background`, and get rid of the event handler altogether.

Comment: thanks @Mike. The second solution worked for me fine. I just wrote another style and when clicking on the label just apply that style programmatically.